# NullreferenceException unhandled when trying to use stored procedure in PropertyChanging event in entity model

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I realise that I am almost certainly being dense but this is starting to bug me, if you'll pardon the pun.

In my entity datamodel I have a partial class for an entity and within that I have added code to a PropertyChanging event to (I had hoped) assign the value to another of the entity's values based on the call to a stored procedure imported into the model and taking the value of the property in whose propertychanging event it is being used as a parameter.

The basic syntax of the call being made (in vb I should add) is;

```
    Private Sub OnVesselIdChanging(value As Integer)
    PortOfLanding = tp.GetDefaultVesselLandingPort(value).SingleOrDefault
End Sub
```

Used as is it causes a 'NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code'.  So to counter this I have tried wrapping it in a try catch block and various other constructs in order to catch null.  Obviously I am missing exactly what the null reference is, I know a parameter of the correct value is being passed to the function and I know that there is data in the underlying database to return a value so why is this happening.

I'd like to make proper use of the entity data model so actively understanding the cause of this would be of great help.

Many thanks for your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: In the details of the exception does it have an inner exception that tells you which object is null?

Comment: The answer to this turned out to be stupidly simple, reinforcing the fact that I'm having a 'dense' day.

In the function call tp refers to the entities collection and I had inadvertently declared it as;

Private tp as TPEnties as opposed to what it should have been  Private tp as New TPEntities

The Null reference I was getting was because the tp wasn't an actual instance of my entities collection and therefore by definition I guess the function itself didn't exist.